# Resteasy Client Register filter for all services

Tags: java, resteasy

It`s possible to register one filter in RestEasy that will works for any instance? Today I have a lot of services thats use one client

for example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
WebTarget target = client.target(ulrBase);
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) target;
this.servico = rtarget.proxy(UsuarioServiceClient.class);
```

but now I have to pass one header prop, so I create this:

public class AuthHeadersRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

```
   @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("xx-Authorization", ((IntegraUI) UI.getCurrent()).getSessionToken());
    }
}
```

but for all Client I need to insert this line:

```
client.register(new AuthHeadersRequestFilter());
```

So, can I configure to every place i create one client, this filter will be registered automatic?

tks

Answer (score 1):

### A step back

How many [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances are you playing with?

[`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances are heavy-weight objects and you are supposed to have only a **small number** of instances and reuse them when possible. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

> `Client`s are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a `Client` instance may be a rather expensive operation. It is therefore advised to construct only a small number of `Client` instances in the application. `Client` instances must be properly closed before being disposed to avoid leaking resources.

### Registering filters and interceptors

RESTEasy won't register filters and interceptors automatically on your [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html). It happens on server side when a filter or interceptor is annotated with [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html). But on client side, you must register the filters and interceptors *manually*.

Instead of registering filters and interceptors in the [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance, you could register them in a [`Configuration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html) instance and use it to create the [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance:

```java
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.register(MyClientResponseFilter.class);
config.register(new AnotherClientFilter());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
```

It might be useful when creating more than one client with the same configuration.